# Diffusion from an instantaneous spherical source with a continuous spherical sink

Tags: differential-equations, diffusion

I assume this is a solved problem, but I cannot find the solution in some common sources, so I am asking here. Suppose you have diffusion of a molecule (diffusion coefficient $D$) from an instantaneous spherical source of radius $\alpha$ and uniform concentration $C_0$, and without loss of generality, centered at the origin in 3D. Outside this sphere, the initial concentration is zero. For an infinite domain, which is what I'm interested in, I know the solution, $C(r,t)$, of this problem to be

$C(r,t) = \frac{1}{2}C_0\left(\mathrm{erf}\frac{r+\alpha}{2(Dt)^{1/2}} + \mathrm{erf}\frac{r-\alpha}{2(Dt)^{1/2}} - \frac{2(Dt)^{1/2}}{r\pi^{1/2}}[e^{-(r-\alpha)^2/4Dt} - e^{-(r+\alpha)^2/4Dt}]\right)$,

from Carslaw and Jaeger. Now suppose you introduce a sphere with center $r'$ and radius $\alpha$ that takes up the molecule at a rate $\mu$ (proportional to $C$). What would the solution then be? I'm actually more interested in the average $C$ inside the spherical sink, so if that is easier to obtain (because of some spherical symmetry), that would be great. I presume this has been solved, or I'm missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated!

Additionally, I would be interested in this same problem but where the molecule is taken up at a different rate $\eta$ outside of both spheres. This problem is less essential, though.

Edit: per request, below is a diagram of the full problem. $\Gamma = 1$ inside the red sphere, $0$ outside. $\Gamma^{-1}$ is the inverse. $\Gamma^{-1}$ term is neglected for the first subproblem.

[image: Problem diagram]

Comment: A diagram would be very helpful.

Comment: Okay, I will post an edit in a few minutes with a diagram.

Comment: I would be surprised if this has a closed-form analytical solution;  there's not enough symmetry.  You *might* be able to work something up via separation of variable in spherical coordinates but it probably would be in the form of an infinite sum.

Comment: Hm, I see what you're saying. If we neglected the spherical sink and just considered a uniform sink everywhere outside the source, that might have enough symmetry for an analytical solution?

Comment: How can the sink absorption rate be independent of concentration – what if concentration falls to zero? And you might research and see if Diffusion Dipole solution exists, or Heat conduction dipole which may be analogous

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into that. Fair point about the rate, I'll edit the question to consider a rate proportional to concentration.